# word cloud in python with customised random colour generation

Tags: python, colors, word-cloud

I saw this function to generate a word cloud online however I am unable to figure out how to change the colour in the `def_random_func`. Say if I want orange, right now the code always produces a green-coloured word cloud. Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

def random_color_func(word=None, font_size=None, position=None, orientation=None, font_path=None, random_state=None):
    h = int(360.0 * 45.0 / 255.0)
    s = int(100.0 * 255.0 / 255.0)
    l = int(100.0 * float(random_state.randint(60, 120)) / 255.0)

    return "hsl({}, {}%, {}%)".format(h, s, l)

file_content = open("rr.txt").read()
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path=r'C:\Windows\Fonts\Verdana.ttf',
                      stopwords=STOPWORDS,
                      background_color='white',
                      width=1200,
                      height=1000,
                      color_func=random_color_func
                      ).generate(file_content)

plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you *tried* modifying that function to constrain the colours it produces? Writing an alternative version?

Comment: No i have not i am not able to understand as to what parameter should i tweak?

Comment: Well it's restricting colors to the region of the HSL color cube with H=45º, S=100%, 60<L<120. You could visualize that with any online HSL-to-RGB visualizer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `random_color_func()` is creating colours of the same hue but with different luminosities. You just need decide which hue you want. So for orange, you could consider using a value of `21`, for example:

```
def random_color_func(word=None, font_size=None, position=None,  orientation=None, font_path=None, random_state=None):
    h = int(360.0 * 21.0 / 255.0)
    s = int(100.0 * 255.0 / 255.0)
    l = int(100.0 * float(random_state.randint(60, 120)) / 255.0)

    return "hsl({}, {}%, {}%)".format(h, s, l)
```

The hue value is in the range `0-360`, you can use an online colour picker to find a suitable value (try Googling [colour picker](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=colour+picker) for example). The code is just converting from the range `0-255` which is another common standard. So rather than convert, you could just make `h = 30`.

This would give you something like:

[image: orange wordcloud]

You could change the randint range to make it brighter.